# How to enter Number and Arithmatic characters in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I would like to be able to enter numbers as well as arithmetic operators in a `TextEdit` to represent latitude and longitude.  So I need numbers, decimal points, and additional and subtraction operators (+/-)

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/dia_latitude"
    style="@style/Heading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

Comment: i have combine two xml attributes with | sign e.g android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `numberSigned`.

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```

For infos, you can find the list of possible input types [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType).